# Spring boot + MongoDB

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I'm working with Spring boot + MongoDB, and I've tried to deploy this application, but I have this exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    ... 63 common frames omitted
```

this is my code:

POM:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

AddressDAOImpl:

```
package pe.com.microexample.daoimpl;

import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import pe.com.microexample.bean.Address;
import pe.com.microexample.dao.AddressDAO;
import pe.com.microexample.repository.AddressRepository;
@Repository
public class AddressDAOImpl implements AddressDAO{

    @Autowired
    private AddressRepository addressRepository;

}
```

AddressRepository:

```
package pe.com.microexample.repository;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;
import pe.com.microexample.bean.Address;

public interface AddressRepository extends MongoRepository<Address, Integer>{

    Address getAddress();

}
```

Any idea about this exception?

Comment: I assume this is working in the test environment and the issue arises only when you try to deploy? Is that the case? Check if the required libraries are there in the classpath.

Comment: Actually, no. I'm working a dev environment and I have all dependencies in my classpath.

Comment: Can you add version of Spring-Boot?

Comment: Don't worry, I fixed. I had to add this dependency in my pom.xml <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
   <version>1.10.4.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>

Answer (score 0):

## maven dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

=======================================================================

## application.properties

```
server.port = 8080
spring.data.mongodb.database=user_db
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
```

=======================================================================

## Repository

public interface UserRepository extends MongoRepository{

## }

**for reference use below link:(step by step explanation)**

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Tq2Q7EzhSA&t=7s